# MySQL Constraint - Allow column values that match a master table identifier

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, constraints, relation

I'm guessing how to do the correct contrains to the following tables:

Table **m_option**:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(32)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(255)| NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table **m_option_value**:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(32)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| option   | int(32)     | NO   | INDX| NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(255)| NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Table **product**:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id       | int(32)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name     | varchar(255 | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| option   | int(32)     | NO   | INDX| NULL    |       |
| opt_val  | int(32)     | NO   | INDX| NULL    |       |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

In table **product**, columns "option" and "opt_val" are indexes and have a contraint. "option" is constrained to foreign key "id" in table **m_option** and "opt_val" is constrained to foreign key "id" in table **m_option_value**. What I'm trying to achieve is to constrain "opt_val" values not only to its master table but current table column **option**. I mean, I only want to allow values in "opt_val" if two conditions are met: value must exist in **option** (already achieved with regular constrain) and value must have same master table identifier as "option" column value. If I didn't express mysqlf correctly, I'll put examples:

Table **m_option** values:

- 1 - Color
- 2 - Shape

Table **m_option_values** values:

- 1 - 1 (Color) - Red
- 2 - 1 (Color) - Blue
- 3 - 2 (Shape) - Square
- 4 - 2 (Shape) - Circle

Table **product** values:

- 1 - Toy1 - 1 (Color) - 1 (Red) **CORRECT**
- 2 - Toy2 - 2 (Shape) - 3 (Square) **CORRECT**
- 3 - Toy3 - 1 (Color) - 4 (Circle) **ALLOWED BUT INCORRECT**

Row 3 "opt_val" column is incorrect because the column should only allow "Color" values, defined in "m_option_values" with "option" value set as "1".

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong foreign key definition.  Presumably:

```
create table option_values (
    . . .,
    unique (option, name)
);
```

Then you need a composite reference:

```
create table products (
    . . .,
    foreign key (option, opt_val) references option_values (option, name),
    foreign key (option) references options(id)
);
```